# How to send pdf from server to browser

Tags: node.js, stream

In the current configuration, we have implemented a feature in AWS where stickiness has been enabled for a specific target group, particularly for downloading results. However, disabling this feature disrupts the functionality. The backend workflow involves making requests to a third-party service to obtain PDF files, which are subsequently stored on the local disk of the EC2 instance. The server then serves these PDF files to the requesting user. An inherent challenge arises when a user is connected to a different EC2 instance, as the PDF files are confined to the instance on which they were initially stored, rendering them inaccessible to users connected to alternative instances.

To address this issue and ensure seamless accessibility of PDF files across multiple EC2 instances, a solution involving centralized storage and distribution is warranted.

Here is the current implementation
`const pdfData = await someThirdParty(id)

```
  if (!pdfData.data.data.success) { throw new Error(pdfData.data.data.message) }

  fs.writeFileSync(
    filePath,
    pdfData.data.data.report.replace(/^data:application\/pdf;base64,/, ''),
    'base64',
    (err) => {
      throw new Error(err)
    }
  ) `
```

Currently I am storing this pdf in nodecache

One Solution I can think of storing the file in s3 buckets but I don't want to store there due to obvious reason. What I want that I directly serve pdf file to the user without storing it on locally on server

Generate PDF on Demand:
Fetch or generate the PDF from the third-party service when a user requests to download.

Stream PDF Directly:
Stream the PDF content directly to the user's browser without saving it on the server.

Serve PDF to User:
Send the streamed PDF data as the HTTP response for the user to download.

This ensures PDFs are served to users without storing them locally, maintaining a serverless and efficient system.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [PIPE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-stream-readable-pipe-method/)

And you would use it like so :

```js
app.get('/download_pdf', (req, res) => {
    // get a readable stream
    let pdf_read_stream = get_from_third_party();
    // set headers
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; your_file.pdf");
    // send to client
    pdf_read_stream.pipe(res);
});
```

That way even if the file is very heavy, it will sent while it's downloaded from third party storage